# How to load animated svg in android?

Tags: java, android, svg, android-glide, svg-animate

I have a SVG-file, its code is below, which is animated. I want to use it in an Android native application. How can I use that svg file? I know about using svg with glide, I tested that from below sample. Normal svg are working but not this one.
https://github.com/bumptech/glide/tree/master/samples/svg

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <svg width='124px' height='124px' xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid" class="uil-ring-alt">
     <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" fill="none" class="bk"></rect>
     <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="rgba(255,255,255,0.259)" fill="none" stroke-width="10" stroke-linecap="round"></circle><circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="#ffffff" fill="none" stroke-width="6" stroke-linecap="round">
          <animate attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" dur="3s" repeatCount="indefinite" from="0" to="502"></animate>
          <animate attributeName="stroke-dasharray" dur="3s" repeatCount="indefinite" values="150.6 100.4;1 250;150.6 100.4"></animate>
     </circle>
</svg>
```

Please suggest me any library or code sample thanks.